# Delete everything until certain string or character in python

Tags: python

I need to read a file and  delete everything until a certain string occurs. It's jut simple and I wrote the code but it do not work. It returns me the whole content of the file.

**My input file:**

```
/****************************************************************
*
*  Function Name:     ab
*  Input Parameter:   cd
*  output Parameter:  ef
*  Return Value:      hi
*
****************************************************************/

#include "file_a.h"
#include "file_b.h"

static inline function(int a, int b){
...
...
...
...
}
```

I have to delete everything until :

```
static inline function(int a, int b){
```

so that this statement will be the first line in the new file.

**My Code**

```
TAG =  'static'

def delete_until(fileName,outfile):
    tag_found = False
    with open ('output.txt',"w") as out:
        with open(fileName,'r') as f:

            for line in f:
                if not tag_found:
                    if line.strip() == TAG:
                        tag_found = True
                    else:
                        out.write(line)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fileName =  'myfile.txt'
    outfile = 'output.txt'
    delete_until(fileName,outfile)
```

The new file has again the whole content. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're analysing code files, they're usually small enough to load into memory. At that point, a single `string.find` call should do it.

```
with open(fileName,'r') as fin, open('output.txt',"w") as fout:
    text = fin.read()
    i = text.find('static')
    if i > -1:
        fout.write(text[i:])
```

This writes:

```
static inline function(int a, int b){
...
...
...
...
}
```

to `output.txt`.

---

If there's a chance that `static` appears inside a comment before an *actual* `static` function, and assuming the code files you're analysing were written by someone sane, you can check for a newline prepended to the keyword. The only changes are here:

```
i = text.find('\nstatic') 
if i > -1:
    fout.write(text[i + 1:])
```

[Credit to JFF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48384137/delete-everything-until-certain-string-or-character-in-python/48384208?noredirect=1#comment83755553_48384208).

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Good point... hmm... Will need to parse the file line-wise for that.

Comment: I would have used `\nstatic` to check for start of line. Less changes to your code :) then slice with i+1

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Good idea, beats line-wise... I've added it in :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`sed`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed):

```
$ sed '1,/static inline function(int a, int b){/d' < your-file.c
```

Comment: this deletes the "static" line, which is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your code fails because of this test:

```
if line.strip() == TAG:
```

You defined `TAG`'s content this way:

```
TAG =  'static'
```

but the line you just read is:

```
'static inline function(int a, int b){'
```

This means you can't compare using just the `==` operator. Depending of what are your requirements, either change the value of `TAG` to match what you are searching (which would be the wisest thing to do, since having a `static` in the comments would match too), or change the way you look for that string.

Comment: that's only 1 bug, there are others.

Answer (score 0):

```
def delete_until(fileName,outfile):
    tag_found = False
    with open ('output.txt',"w") as out:
        with open(fileName,'r') as f:

            for line in f:
                if not tag_found:
                    if TAG in line:
                        tag_found = True
                if tag_found:
                    out.write(line)
```

Comment: Please explain what you did. Answers consisting of 100% code are most likely not to be understood.

Comment: 1. as explained by liberforce the if line.strip() == TAG: was wrong, so i substitute it with a right statement if TAG in line: and .split() doesn t matter; 2. the indentation was wrong and the flag tag_found  has to be checked anyway after its set.